# Is it possible to aggregate fitness data from multiple users in the same web app using the Google Fit REST API?

Tags: java, rest, google-fit

I am currently working on a web application which is supposed to track multiple users and monitor their health parameters (pulse, number of steps, location etc). What I've currently thought about is having an administration interface which aggregates all data sent by the registered users. I want to use the Google Fit REST API.

Is it possible to fetch the workout data of all registered/active users in the same screen, being authenticated only with the admin account? Does Google provide such feature? I know there is something similar for the Gmail API. I am looking for some kind of live tracking solution, but using the specified API.

I've already read the API documentation but I didn't find such thing yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You have to make requests authenticated as each of the individual users.

If you look [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataset/aggregate), the `userId` is documented thus:

> Aggregate data for the person identified. Use `me` to indicate the authenticated user. Only `me` is supported at this time.

Requesting another user's data is not a supported feature.

With that said, if a user grants you an OAuth token to access their fitness data, there is no reason that you can't get multiple users' data with multiple requests.

Comment: Thank you! I was also thinking of persisting the OAuth tokens of all users and I hope that will be enough. My main purpose is to get a dashboard-like screen where the administrator can track the registered users. The registration process is also intended to be managed by the administrator.